# Javascript regex groups not capturing repeating group?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I have the following regex and test strings:

[image]

When inspecting the matches I noticed that on Match 3 ("## smaller header") I have the following groups:

1. ## #
2. header

rather than:

1. ## #
2. **smaller header**

I want to capture "smaller header" on its own group.

Comment: Post the code itself, not pictures of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeat the `\s\w+`s inside the captured group:

```js
const str = '## smaller header'
const re = /^(#{1,6})([\s\w]+)/;
console.log(str.match(re));
```

If you don't want to capture the first space in the second group, then match it outside instead:

```js
const str = '## smaller header'
const re = /^(#{1,6})\s([\w ]+)/;
console.log(str.match(re));
```